# c# concatenating two video streams basic

Tags: c#

first time here. I'm trying to merge two video streams using C# and output the stream via web api. the goal is to append the 2nd video to the first video so they run sequentially as a single stream. The idea is that I have multiple small "clips" I'd like to run (or rotate) through.

I've managed to successfully return a single video stream via **PushStreamContent** but am not struggling to see if I could return two video streams as one in the same request call.

used this example here:
http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/

my initial thought was just to add the current file stream to the end of the output stream but it doesn't seem to work. I am guessing because the streams of video replays on the client end have time stamps and it's not as simple as just appending it to the end.

there's some suggestions revolving around looking at http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/ , but is there a very simple solution that I missed for a simple case I'm looking out for?

Thanks!

edit: added some clarity.

Comment: Hi,

I have two files , say _a.mp4_ and _b.mp4_ and I want to return it as a+b.mp4 , as a single video stream.

Comment: Apologies, yes. I'd like to append the 2nd video to my first, so the playback seems like a single video.

I'd like it to simply run sequentially.

my use case is that I have several parts of a video clip and I'd like to stream them all as one.

Comment: I think you are looking for "Digital containers". Since you have 2 streams, you need to create a container to let the player know how many individual parts are in the stream and their sequence. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_container_format for more details on the concept.